# LibGdx setScreen() doesnt work in HTML5 but on Desktop

Tags: java, javascript, html, libgdx

i am programming a Game which should be playable in the Webbroweser (HTML5). So i created a Project with HTML & Desktop.

```
((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new GameOver("Level1"));
```

This line works fine in the Desktop Version but it doesnt work in the HTML5 Version at the Webbrowser. If I klick ["I"] in the Desktop Version it is changing the Screen but if I press ["I"]
i the HTML5 version, then just a short framedrop happen.

What can i do?

Kind Regards,

Jona

Comment: having the same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582870/infinite-loop-in-my-loading-class-when-debugging-compiling-for-html5-test-proje