# Infinite loop in my loading class when debugging/compiling for HTML5 (test_project available)

Tags: gwt, libgdx

Recently I added a loading class to my libgdx games (libgdx version 1.3.1). It works fine for the projects android, desktop and IOS.

However, for HTML5 my game never runs and only shows a black screen. Then I found out there is constant(if not infinite) call to `.setScreen (new Test(game))` in the code below in my `Loading` class when I debug it:

```
   @Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // Clear the screen
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (game.manager.update() && timeLoading < 0) { // Load some, will return true if done loading

            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener())
            .setScreen(new Test(game)); 
        //}
    }else{
        timeLoading-=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }


    // Show the loading screen
    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
}
```

To make there is nothing wrong with my game I create a project from the scratch using the libgdx gradel tool, compile it using the gwt and the html5 project worked fine.

Then I just added my `Loading` class in the middle, the desktop works great, but the html5 now behaves as I mentioned above.

Any ideas?

I have uploaded a test project 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ukvik4fcnpzl97a/test_ptoject%202.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem. issue

```
 public class HtmlLauncher extends GwtApplication {

        @Override
        public GwtApplicationConfiguration getConfig () {
                return new GwtApplicationConfiguration(640, 960);
        }

        @Override
        public ApplicationListener getApplicationListener () {
                return new ApplicationListener ();
        }
    }
```

htmlLauncher return new `ApplicationListener`,so 
when you `((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener())`
your always get new `ApplicationListener`,

use in your screen a reference to `ApplecationListener`

```
public MainMenuScreen(ApplicationListener  applicationListener ) 
{
    this.applicationListener=applicationListener ;
}

applicationListener.setScreen();
```